# ConnectionResetError while Uploading Image to Telegraph

Tags: python, telegraph

I'm trying to upload image to telegraph

My Code:

```
from telegraph import Telegraph

def upload_to_telegraph(image_path):
  uploaded_image = Telegraph().upload_file(image_path)
  image_url = f"https://telegra.ph{uploaded_image[0]['src']}"
  return image_url

print(upload_to_telegraph("Picture1.jpg"))
```

Error I'm Getting.

`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))`

Edit: its working in replit but not in my editor any solutin?